# How to decode html in KnockoutJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I'm currently trying to decode HTML which is persisted in my database and returned to the model as serialized JSON and then mapped to a KnockoutJS view model.

Problem is that the HTML is being displayed like so:

```
<p> This is a test</p>
```

I can't seem to use the HTML decode function otherwise I get the invalid $ error

e.g. throws the above error:

```
@Html.Decode( ${ Content } );
```

Comment: Have you tried `@Html.Decode(' ${ Content } ');`. Maybe putting quotes around the template will still work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer through a colleague's help. 
I'm using KnockoutJS with JQuery templates. The actual syntax is:

```
{{html Content}}
```

Strange syntax but there you have it;)

Comment: This is using the `html` binding as described here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html  It will set the `innerHTML` of the element that is is bound to.  Take care with your event handlers using this method as elements will be destroyed and recreated

Comment: You may consider moving away from the JQuery templates library now that it has been deprecated...  http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

Answer (score 1):

Try using @Html.Raw() instead <